# What exactly is compute_gradients returning and how does it depend on batch_size?

Tags: tensorflow

Please excuse my rookie understanding of TensorFlow, Thanks in advance for the help!

I am trying to compute the gradients using `compute_gradients()` wrt the embedding inputs of my loaded model.

My batch_size is 250 and embd_size is 300.

I want to compute the gradients of all my inputs for 250 test examples, 
 so `predicted_y` is a numpy list of the values predicted by the model of shape `[250,1]` so the `x_test` that I provide in the `feed` dict is of shape `[250, 300]`.

I have already tried this similar question 
[What does compute_gradients return in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982081/what-does-compute-gradients-return-in-tensorflow)
but I didn't completely understand the role of batch_size in compute_gradients()

```
def get_gradients(model, predicted_y):

    variables_fed = []
    gradients_fe = []
    inputs_here_fed = []

    optimizer_here = model.gradients
    inputs_here = model.inputs
    embedding_here = model.embedding
    cost_here = model.cost

    print(len(predicted_y))


    gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer_here.compute_gradients(cost_here, embedding_here))
    print("gradients object: {}".format(gradients[0]))

    opt = optimizer_here.apply_gradients(list(zip(gradients, variables)))
    # we do not have to run the optimizer as we do not want to BP

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

        sess.run(init)
        test_state = sess.run(model.initial_state)

        feed = {model.inputs: x_test[0:len(predicted_y)], # dims should match predicted_y
                model.labels: predicted_y[:, None], #converting 1d to 2d array
                model.keep_prob: dropout,
                model.initial_state: test_state}

        # test = sess.run(opt, feed_dict=feed)

        gradients_fed = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict=feed)

        # inputs_here_fed = sess.run(inputs_here, feed_dict=feed)
        # variables_fed = sess.run(variables, feed_dict=feed)

    return variables_fed, gradients_fed, inputs_here_fed

def get_gradients_values(gradients): # takes IndexedSlices Object which store gradients as input

    l = gradients[0].values
    print("Shape of gradients list: {}".format(l.shape))

    return l
```

After I feed the values in `sess.run(gradients, feed)`, I extract the values of the `IndexedSlices` object obtained and stored it as a list `grads`. I expected to get `grads` with dimentionality `[250, 300]`, corresponding to the gradients for all my inputs for each test example Instead I get `[50000, 300]` which I cannot explain.

I tried varying the batch_size too see what happens but it gives me mismatch between input shapes error. I tried understanding the compute_gradients() code on github but its too obscure for someone with my basic understanding.

How do I get the gradients of all inputs for each of my test set examples?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the dimensions that gradients returns from `compute_gradients()` is correct according to my `x_train` dimensions, which is `(250,200,300)` not `(250,300)` that I thought earlier. The computed `IndexedSlices` object has a `values` property which flattens the output to `(250*200,300)` and a `indices` property which is of same dims as `values` which gives us the index of each word in the vocabulary you used for tokenization.

Also, while using `compute_gradients()` we need to make sure in the above code that `batch_size == len(predicted_y)` always, or it will give a shape mismatch error. To get gradients for one example, set `batch_size = 1` and make sure `predicted_y` only contains 1 test example. The gradients object obtained with these parameters will be of size `(200,300)` and to get the attribution/gradient measure for each input we can use `np.sum(gradients, axis = 1)` to sum across the columns.